# How to understand android activity is launched directly or first killed- then recreated?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

As you all knows all android activities create, start, resume, run, pause, stop, destroy. This process is shown well in the [android manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

In this lifecycle is there any possiblity to understand activity is created which way? I mean how can I understand whether activity is called directly or activity is created once then killed by android os and then recreated since user navigates back?

More basically how can I understand whether an activity is in its second life or first life?

**Edit:** Why do I need this?
In my design I have a main page where the data is loaded from the net. And when the user clicks some details, it puts the data in a static object just like session in web. This works well normally.

But when a user starts detail activity in second life, he data in static object is killed, and I got nullpointer exception.

I have 4 projects having same architecture so I want to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got the flow chart information there.  You can always keep some state for later use by storing the fact of your `Activity`'s demise during `onDestory()` or similar.  Then, the next time your `Activity` is resumed, you will know if you were actually destroyed or just stopped.  I don't think you get any of that information for free from the OS, since it's not supposed to matter in the ideal case.

Comment: android provides a great flowchart on the lifecycle of an activity; additionally, they give direct hooks into each of those lifecycle events.  It would be very easy to track which one and from where you are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

you should not distinguish between these, since even after it has been destroyed (at least the method has been called) it might "come back" just in the state as it was when it was destroyed. Which could be different than from the very initial state when it was created the first time.

Please explain the reason why you need this - you should "rethink" your issue, since Android is really behaving "strange" concering this question.

It is better to design your project livecycle according to Android system behaviour - which is actually not documented anywhere regarding this point (at least I have not come accross any good doc so far)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to know when your activity has been destroyed by the OS or when it has only been paused. Simply use logcat statements:

```
onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("Activity", "Paused");
}

onDestory() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("Activity", "Destroyed");
}
```

You can do the same for onCreate(), onResume(), anything really.